# Como puedo setear varios ImageView en una Activity

Tags: android

Este es mi CompleteActivity.java :

private static final String TAG = "Tarea";
private static final String REPTIL = "Reptil";
private static final String AVE = "Ave";
private static final String ANFIBIO = "Anfibio";
private static final String MAMIFERO = "Mamifero";
private static final String OTRO = "Desconocida";

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete);

mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
reportesEspecies = new ArrayList<>();
ButterKnife.bind(this);

traerDoc();

}


public void traerDoc(){
String doc = getIntent().getStringExtra("doc");

mFirestore.collection("Data")
        .document(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()).collection("Reportes")
        .whereEqualTo("doc",doc)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                        tvDireccion.setText(document.get("direccion").toString());
                        tvEspecie.setText(document.get("especie").toString());
                        tvFechayHora.setText(document.get("fechaYhora").toString());

                        switch (tvEspecie.getText().toString().trim()){
                            case "Ave1":
                                if (tvEspecie.getText().toString().equals(AVE)){
                                    btnDos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rapaces);
                                    btnCuatro.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gallinazo);
                                    btnSiete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.otros);
                                }else{
                                    return;
                                }
                                break;
                            case "Anfibio1":
                                if (tvEspecie.getText().toString().equals(ANFIBIO)){
                                    btnDos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sapos);
                                    btnSiete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rana);
                                }else{
                                    return;
                                }
                                break;
                            case "Reptil1":
                                if (tvEspecie.getText().toString().equals(REPTIL)){
                                    btnDos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lagarto);
                                    btnCuatro.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.culebra);
                                    btnSiete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reptiles);
                                }else{
                                    return;
                                }
                                break;
                            case "Mamifero1":
                                if (tvEspecie.getText().toString().equals(MAMIFERO)){
                                    btnUno.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roedores);
                                    btnDos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.felino);
                                    btnTres.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.primates);
                                    btnCuatro.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comadreja);
                                    btnCinco.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zariguella);
                                    btnSeis.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zorro);
                                    btnSiete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oso);
                                }else{

                                    return;
                                }

                                break;
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se presento un incidente al obtener los datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

}

Necesito que se ubiquen las subEspecies segun la especie que se obtenga en el tvEspecie y pense usando un switch y un setBackgroundResource Agradezco cualquier ayuda! No tengo en el momento error pero tampoco estoy logrando lo que necesito :/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:hint="Especie: "
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEspecie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:hint="Fecha y Hora: "
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFechayHora"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Default"
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:hint="Dirección: "
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDireccion"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:text="Default"
                android:textColor="@color/browser_actions_bg_grey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:text="@string/seleccionespecie" />



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnCinco"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnSeis"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnSiete"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnOcho"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnUno"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnDos"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnTres"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnCuatro"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvUd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `setBackgroundResource()` esta diseñado para establecer drawables, no imágenes PNG o JPG. Un recurso drawable es un archivo xml.

Para poder establecer el background de las vistas tienes que obtener un drawable a partir de las imágenes, y después establecerlo usando el método `setBackground()`.

El drawable lo puedes obtener de la siguiente manera

```
Drawable felino = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.felino, null);
```

Y luego establecerlo usando el método setBackground

```
btnDos.setBackground(felino);
```

---

Referencias

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackground(android.g...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#drawables-from-images

---

### Actualizacion

En vez de establecer el fondo de los ImageViews por que no estableces su propiedad src utilizando el metodo `setImageResource`.

Ej:

```
btnDos.setImageResource(R.drawable.felino);
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar no muestra error pero sigue sin cargarme los jpg ejemplo si tvEspecie es = a Ave deben de habilitarse 3 botones de animales para pulsar alguno pero si tvEspecie es igual a Mamifero deben habilitarse 8 botones de animales totalmente diferentes

Comment: A que te refieres con habilitarse?

Comment: Disculpa, me refiero a que aparezcan o se muestren en la actividad pero solo con la condición o no se si estoy construyendo incorrectamente la condicion porque el campo AVE ANFIBIO MAMIFERO y REPTIL son tipo String

Comment: Y actualmente que pasa, no se muestran ninguno o se muestran todos?

Comment: Puedes agregar el archivo xml de la actividad

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta

Comment: La misma la acabo de actualizar

Comment: Gracias David, Bendiciones me ha servido mucho tu ayuda efectivamente con setImageResource lo solucione no se porque no lo habia intentado antes